# Is there a programmatically way to force a crawler to not index specific images?

Tags: python, html, django, seo

I want to stop crawlers from indexing specific images on my website, but only if they're older than a specific date. However, the crawler shall not stop indexing the page where the image is currently linked.

My initial approach was to write a script which adds the URL of the image to 'robots.txt', but I think the file will become huge, as we talk about a really huge amount of potential images.

My next idea was to use the `<meta name="robots" content="noimageindex">` tag, but I think this approach can be error prone, as I could forget to add this tag to a template where I might want to stop crawlers from indexing the image. It's also redundant and the crawler will ignore all images.

My question is: do you know a programmatically way to force a crawler too not index a image, if a condition (in my case the date) is true? Or is my only possibility to stop the crawler from indexing the whole page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on top of what you had in mind, you could just create a separate place to keep the images that you don't want to be indexed, write a script to move files to that location once they're "expired" and just add the url to the the robots.txt file. Perhaps something like `/expired_images*`.

Comment: Note that according to google itself it won't prevent images discovered otherwise (thru links etc) to be indexed, cf https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/23CdzZ5Z8Bc

Comment: From the same link, the best solution would be to use your front server (Apache, Nginx etc) to add a `X-Robots-Tag "noindex"` header for those images.

Comment: The obvious solution didn't come to my mind. Thank you, I will investigate it further.